# C++ How Do You Pass Multiple Parameters?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, c++11

Let's assume I have a probability class with a method that computes the average of an array. Because it's possible that this method be passed an array of floats, doubles, ints, etc, I assumed it would be appropriate to make this method a template method.

But when passing an array, I have to define a the type of array and length of an array. So my question is: how do I configure the template to accept two inputs? I have referenced the web but have had limited luck in seeing a good example.

- Is it valid to define templates to accept parameters that are ints, floats, etc.?

I've posted my code below

Probability Header

```
#ifndef COFFEEDEVMATH_PROBABILITY_H
#define COFFEEDEVMATH_PROBABILITY_H

class Probability
{
    public:
         Probability(void);
        template <typename T, int N>
        void ExpectedValueDataSet(const std::array<T, N>& data)
        {
            T test = data[0]; // This is irrelevant, but simply a place holder example.
        }

    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // COFFEEDEVMATH_PROBABILITY_H
```

Main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Probability.h>

int main()
{

    float hoor[] = {3, 3, 1, 1};
    Probability prob;
    prob.ExpectedValueDataSet(hoor, 4);

}
```

Comment: it's the whole class that should be a template, not just one method.

Comment: For starters, `int` isn't the second template parameter of `std::array`, so it can't be deduced. The type is `size_t`.

Comment: Why exactly? I feel like it would be more appropriate to have a single "Probability Object" that can operate on different kind of data that you throw at it. Is what i'm trying to do not legal in C++?

Comment: Instead of C-style arrays, why not use `std::vector` or `std::array`? Then you don't have to worry about passing lengths, they are a part of the container.

Comment: @Teague If you want a probability object that doesn't hold any state (no member variables, just a grouping of functions with related purpose) you could make all of the functions static and never instantiate this object but rather just use its namespace as a logical way to group everything.

Comment: What you need is a good c++ book to read the chapter on templates, but you can pass template parameters like: `prob.ExpectedValueDataSet<float, 4>(hoor);`

Comment: I suspect what you're *trying* to do is something on the lines of `template <typename T, std::size_t N> void ExpectedValueDataSet(const T(&data)[N])`, though personally I'd just use iterators and write a set of helpers to acquire them for the various flavors you want to support (fixed array, container, length-specified sequence, etc).

Comment: @Teague I think the problem with this question is that you haven't described what problem you ran into that makes you think having multiple parameters is difficult. I suspect you tried several approaches but got some compiler errors and assumed that those approaches didn't work rather than that you had some easily fixed minor issue such as ordering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it valid to define templates to accept parameters that are ints, floats, etc.?

It's perfectly fine. But to pass an array, you must have an array.

```
std::array<float,4> hoor2 = {3.0f, 3.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
```

In the corresponding template you must use `size_t`, not `int`

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
void ExpectedValueDataSet(const std::array<T, N>& data) {}
```

> how do I configure the template to accept two inputs?

Just add an additional parameter. To pass a pointer and a length, you create a template that receives a pointer and a length

```
template <typename T>
void ExpectedValueDataSet( T const * data, int N){}
```

There is also a special syntax for c style arrays that will allow you to pass them without having to specify the length, as that argument will be deduced from the type.

```
template <typename T, size_t N >
void ExpectedValueDataSet( const T (&data)[N]) { }
```

Together we have

```
class Probability
{ 
public:
    template <typename T, size_t N>
    void ExpectedValueDataSet(const std::array<T, N>& data) {}

    template <typename T>
    void ExpectedValueDataSet( T const * data, int N){}

    template <typename T, size_t N>
    void ExpectedValueDataSet(const T (&data)[N]){};
};
```

See live working exampe [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5584393e4f1848e0)

Comment: I think his template's `int N` is intended to be the array size.

Comment: @kfsone right, forgot the c style array. corrected.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you've defined your source array as a shitty C array instead of a `std::array`. If you define your source array as a `std::array`, you won't have this problem.

Also, there's no need to pass the length in addition, as you have with your example.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that you are trying to pass old plain C array `float hoor[]` to function with parameter of type `std::array<T,N>` which is NOT directly compatible with plain C array.

Correct syntax to pass plain C array as reference is:

```
template <size_t N, typename T>
void ExpectedValueDataSet(const T (&data)[N])
{
    T test = data[0];
}
```

Usage example:

```
float hoor_f[] = {3, 3, 1, 1};
ExpectedValueDataSet(hoor_f);

int hoor_i[] = {3, 3, 1, 1};
ExpectedValueDataSet(hoor_i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, I have a feeling that the following is what you *should* be doing:

```
template<typename C>
typename C::value_type average(C const& c)
{
    return std::accumulate(std::begin(c), std::end(c), C::value_type{}) / c.size();
}
```

1. Avoid C-style arrays whenever possible.
2. Favor `std::vector` whenever possible.
3. Genericity over all containers from `std` is good.

The above code satisfies all three and works with the following examples:

```
std::vector<double> vd = { 0., 1., 3., 4.4 };
std::array<float, 4> af = { 3.f, 5.f, 6.f };
std::list<int> li = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can have multiple template arguments but C++ templates offer even more flexibility, you can directly avoid specifying that you are dealing with an array and suppose that you will have access to a `size() const` method, a `value_type` typedef and and overloaded `operator[]`.

This would be enough, so code would become something like:

```
template <typename T>
void calculate(const T& data)
{
    size_t length = data.size();
    using type = typename T::value_type;
    type value = data[0];
    cout << length << " " << value << endl;
}
```

This is more generic of your implementation, it would be able to work with all classes which supports the aforementioned characteristics without even bothering about if it's a `std::array`, or maybe `std::vector` or what else.

Comment: Actually, the generic way of dealing with it is iterators.

Comment: @Puppy: if the OP needs to deal with a custom data structure it's far more straightforward to define a `size()` method, an `operator[]` and a `typedef` that writing a custom iterator. Actually learning how to write a random access iterator properly is not so basic at all.

Comment: Except basically all of the data structures already offer iterators (and for good reason)

Answer (score 0):

Pass a container to a template function like this.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
double average(T t) {
    auto tmp = 0.0;
    for (auto &i : t) {
        tmp += i;
    }
    return tmp/t.size();
}

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    auto a = {1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3};
    auto b = {2, 3, 4, 5};
    auto x = average(a);
    auto y = average(b);
    cout << "x: " << x << endl;
    cout << "y: " << y << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> x: 1.15
>   y: 3.5

And using lambda. The auto keyword in lambdas requires C++14 and later.

```
auto average = [](auto v){
    auto tmp = 0.0;
    for (auto& i : v) {
        tmp += i;
    }
    return tmp/v.size();
};
auto a = {1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4};
auto b = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
auto x = average(a);
auto y = average(b);
cout << "x: " << x << endl;
cout << "y: " << y << endl;
```

> x: 1.25
>   y: 5.5